# How to trigger a sound once after a certain value has been reached

Tags: java, android

How can I adjust the source code so that when I level up, the level up sound should only trigger once?

Now the Sound is reproduced all the time and doesn't stop but I want the level up sound to only trigger a single time for each level up.

```
private void Run(){
    int a = 0;
    do {
        showEmerald();
        a++;
    }while (a<15);//show more emeralds
    vanishEmerald();
    updateScreen();
    handler.postDelayed(this,  600);

    if (points>=25){
        level=2;
        levelup.start();
    }
```

Comment: Please translate everything in your code into English - it'll make it much easier for us to help you *and* make your question more useful to other readers in the future. It's not at all clear which piece of this code plays a sound...

Comment: Besides: consider using a different structure. Right now your "lauf" method is the **central** place that actually controls what is going on. Such a simple solution works for your first ideas, but as soon as you will try to enhance your game, you will run into limitations all over the place. Also bee precise about your naming: you better say something like "entferneSmaragte()" and "aktualisiereBildschirm()" ... be consistent there; and put the verb first always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined it once it hits over 25 points the *If-clause* is always fullfilled and will trigger the levelup. My advise would be to either define If outside the loop or / and reset the counter of the points after the levelup has been triggered.

Something like this:

```
if (points>=25){
    level++;
    levelup.start();
    points = 0
}
```

This way you don't have to increase the level manually everytime and it just increments further everytime by one.